# Dialogflow Carousel Carl to URL

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to create a carousel of images in dialogflow in which when I click on an image it redirects me to a url, creating a basic card if it lets me do it, but my intention is to put several options.

I have tried to make a list, but when I test the implementation the list is displayed again when I click on one of the options.